# Facebook javascript photo upload+tagging API changed last night (2012 Sept.12th)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, photo, tagging

I'm using the Javascript SDK and wanted to upload an image and tag friends at the same time.
Yesterday I got everything working, uploading an image and specifying tags for 9 friends, but when I tried it again today it was broken, the image would still upload and I also get an id and post_id in the response, but tags wouldn't be added anymore. I stripped out all of the unnecessary code and boiled it down to the very basics (see below), without success. However making a second call to /photoId/tags with to/x/y parameters still works.
so my now my questions:

1. did anything in the API change ?
2. did my appId or url get disabled for this kind of tagging ? If so, how can I check/restore ?
3. can anyone confirm this is still working ?

   ```
   FB.api("/me/photos","post",{url:"http://fakeurl.com/image.jpg",tags:[{tag_uid:"23fake42425223",x:50,y:50}]},function(response) {console.log(response);});
   ```

I'm pretty sure the code is alright (correct me if I'm wrong), because when I change any of the parameters i'll get an error response (e.g. I changed the "tag_uid" to "to" results in "(#100) Invalid keys "to... found in param "tags"."). I also tried tag_text, which also uploads the image, but no tag seen at all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you filed a bug report?

Comment: i don't think it's a bug ... it's just facebook doesn't want you to tag pictures for the user anymore (too much spam i guess).