# Facebook Photo Tag not working from september 12

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

My facebook photo tag app was working great until today.I used Following code to tag friends in photo.

```
$attachment = array( 
            'message' => $mes,
            'tags'    => 
              array(
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[0],
                          'x'      => '30',
                          'y'      => '60',
                          ),
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[1],
                          'x'      => '30',
                          'y'      => '50',
                          ), 
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[2],
                          'x'      => '30',
                          'y'      => '70',
                          ),
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[3],
                          'x'      => '30',
                          'y'      => '10',
                          ), 
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[4],
                          'x'      => '10',
                          'y'      => '60',
                          ),
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[5],
                          'x'      => '40',
                          'y'      => '60',
                          ),
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[6],
                          'x'      => '50',
                          'y'      => '60',
                          ),
                    array(
                          'tag_uid'=> $re[7],
                          'x'      => '60',
                          'y'      => '60',
                          ),
                    array(
                          'tag_uid' => $re[8],
                          'x'       => '80',
                          'y'       => '60',
                          ) 
                  )
          );
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$attachment['image'] ='@'.realpath($filename);
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$aid.'/photos', 'POST', $attachment);
```

But This code was not tagging friends any more.It just uploads photo.
Is there any API change in facebook or any alternative working method to tag friends .thanks.

Comment: What kind of images have you been uploading, where they _real_ photos? Have there been any spam reports/complaints (->insights) by users been tagged in your photos be others?

Comment: yea..it gets 10 friends image,,no spam reports..even i try to create new app and different domain names..app is not tagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating the posts and tagging, API will work correctly

---

```
$attachment = array( 
  'message' => $mes,
);
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$attachment['image'] ='@'.realpath($filename);
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$aid.'/photos', 'POST', $attachment);

//tagging
$tags = array(
  'tag_uid'=> $re[0],
  'x'      => '30',
  'y'      => '60',
);
$response = $facebook->api('/'.$photo['id'].'/tags', 'POST', $tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

i can confirm this behaviour, experienced the same issue on javascript SDK, see my post for details:
[Facebook javascript photo upload+tagging API changed last night (2012 Sept.12th)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387764/facebook-javascript-photo-uploadtagging-api-changed-last-night-2012-sept-12th)
as shiba_tsubasa mentioned a two-step upload+tagging will still work, which should be fine for the php sdk (not so nice on the javascript sdk e.g. user shuts down the browser right after the first step)